# Nested transactions in spring

Tags: hibernate, model-view-controller, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

We're building a new application in Spring MVC with Hibernate as persistence solution.
There 're 2 solutions to approach the data layer:

1) In some cases the controller invokes the DAO layer directly. This is done because no business checks need to be performed. So we're bypassing the Service layer for such cases.
Implementing a Service layer for this would turn up in just delegating methods to the DAO layer.
So we're doing the following: Controller -> DAO

2) In other cases we do need some business checks. For this, we use the conventional way:
Controller -> Service -> DAO

In Spring we need to demarcate a Transaction, therefore we put @Transaction annotation on all DAO methods. This works fine doing the Controller -> DAO way. But if we're doing the Controller -> Service -> DAO way, we also need to put a @Transaction annotation on the service method.

This means that we're having nested transactions in some cases.
Is this a good approach?
Do we need to create a new transaction (REQUIRES_NEW) on all DAO methods or rather use the existing transaction (REQUIRED) if one exists?

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default propagation strategy (`REQUIRED`) is a reasonable choice for the most of scenarios, therefore you can safely use it unless you have some very special requirements.

In your second case `REQUIRED` would work almost the same way as if there were no `@Transactional` at DAO methods. The only subtle difference is in rollback-on-exception behavior: transaction is marked as "rollback only" when exception (the one that causes transaction rollback) passes a border of any transactional method, not just a top-level one, so that you won't be able to catch a rollback-causing exception thrown from your DAO method and make transaction commit.

`REQUIRES_NEW` in your case is only needed if you want to be able to rollback inner and outer transactions separately.